# 5 hour layover in Istanbul on separate tickets, is it enough time?

Tags: airport-transfer, turkey, istanbul

I will be traveling from the USA to Istanbul airport. My flight leaves from Denver and I have a connection in Frankfurt, Germany. I will arrive in Istanbul around 1730. I then take a flight to Tunis, Tunisia.

I have to go and collect my luggage and recheck it into Tunis Air because I had to buy two separate tickets. I have 5 hours and I hear that this airport is difficult to navigate. I do have a Turkish visa. Is this enough time, and is there anyway to ensure I do this in the fastest/most efficient way?

Comment: 5 hours are much more than enough on any routine day for IST. Don't worry.

Comment: When is your travel scheduled? A new airport is set to open in Istanbul on 1 January, so we couldn't comment on that. For the current airport (Ataturk) 5 hours is definitely plenty. I'd guess the same will be true for the new airport, but it would be just a guess.

Comment: If the airport's name is Ataturk, Actually it is not diffucult navigate. It is possible that use subway and bus. You can visit places around of airport. You can find many shops which buy a lot kind of gift.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of time for your transit. I have been at the new airport and only had 2 hours on 2 seperate tickets. [Here](https://www.turkishairlines.com/de-de/istanbul-airport/terminal-maps/) is a map of the airport. The airport has good signs and live tables that show how much time you will need to walk to a gate area. To expedite your transit:

- Exit the airplane as early as possible so you can be the first on security check (which they always  have in Turkey) though you dont have to be too feared (Border control is always well staffed, so large queues are unlikely)
- Make sure you know where your departure gate is after checking in your bags

Comment: Does that include the time necessary to go through immigration twice and recheck luggage?

Comment: Yes. It was even 1,5 hours which I needed. But I was there at 11 am, so the airport was not that crowded I guess.